# Find the number of all natural solutions to $0<\sin n < 10^{-12}, \ \ n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: solution-verification, dynamical-systems

> Find the number of all natural solutions to
> $$0<\sin n < 10^{-12}, \ \ n\in \mathbb{N}$$

*My try:* Consider a unit circle on $xy$-plane. Then all values of $\sin n$ can be illustrated by rotating the point $(\cos1,\sin1)$ by an angle of value $1$ radian $(\sin 2, \sin 3, ...)$. Converting this into degree, one gets $\alpha = 180^\circ/\pi$. Since $\alpha$ is irrational, this rotation process cannot be periodic (never coincides with the initial step). Therefore, points of the form $(\cos n,\sin n)$ are dense on the circle, which, particularly, provides that there are infinitely many values of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying  $0<\sin n < 10^{-12}.$

Is there anything I am missing for complete proof?

---

**Update:** Below is my try to complete, taking into note the comments and the answer:

Let $$T_\alpha^{(n)}(x) = x + n\alpha \mod 1$$, where $x$ - initial point, $n$ - number of rotations. In our case $\alpha$ is irrational.

- We should show that all $T_\alpha^{(n)}(x)$ are distinct.
  Assume that $\exists k,i,j:$
  $$T_\alpha^{(i)}(x) = T_\alpha^{(j)}(x) + k, \ \ i \neq j$$
  $$x+i\alpha = x+ j\alpha + k \implies (i-j)\alpha = k$$
  Since $\alpha$ is irrational, we must have $i=j$. Contradiction.

Now, divide $[0,1]$ into $n$ parts, length of $1/n$ each. We know that $x, T_\alpha^{(1)}(x),...,T_\alpha^{(n)}(x)$ are distinct. Thus, by Drichlet's principle, there exists an interval that contains at least two of the terms of the sequence above. Say $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$, $(i \neq j)$
$$|T_\alpha^{(i)}(x)-T_\alpha^{(j)}(x)|<\frac{1}{n}$$

- We should prove that $\forall x_0 \in [0,1], \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists m \in \mathbb{Z}:$
  $$T_\alpha^{(m)}(x) \in \bigcup_\varepsilon(x_0)$$
  We know that
  $$\frac{1}{n} > |T_\alpha^{(i)}(x) - T_\alpha^{(j)}(x)| = |T_\alpha^{(i-j)}(x)-x|$$
  Thus, taking $m:=i-j$, we have
  $$T_\alpha^{(m)}(x) \in \bigcup_\varepsilon(x_0)$$

Therefore, $T_\alpha^{(n)}(x)$ is dense at $[0,1]$.

Comment: Celsius?$\phantom{}$

Comment: Not periodic does not automatically mean dense, but it is in fact dense.

Comment: @anomaly ,  Sorry, edited :)

Comment: There's a classic result that the map $f(x) = x + t$ on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ has $\{f^n(x):\, n\geq 0\}$ dense in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ for any $x$ provided that $t\not\in \mathbb{Q}$. (As for a proof, one approach is via unique ergodicity, if you're familiar with that; or there's a more straightforward but messier proof via a bit of number theory.)

Comment: @VIVID: No problem. :)

Comment: @anomaly - I think I can do it via "a bit of number theory" as you mention. Yet, the first option you suggest seems interesting even if I'm not very familiar with ergodicity :)

Comment: But points of the form $(n,\sin n)$ don't lie on the unit circle. Did you mean $(\cos n,\sin n)$?

Comment: @TonyK - Oops, you're absolutely right!

Comment: If you find one solution $m = 2\pi n + \alpha$ where $0 < \alpha < \sin^{-1}(10^{-12})$, then can you use $m \lceil 2\pi / \alpha \rceil$ if $2\pi / \alpha$ is not an integer, and $m (2\pi / \alpha + 1)$ if $2\pi / \alpha$ is an integer, to always find a ***next*** solution?

Comment: @VIVID: Walters' "Introduction to Ergodic Theory" is pretty good. If I remember correctly, this sort of unique ergodicity result is at the end of the first (or maybe the second?) chapter.

Comment: @anomaly - Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Use the irationality of $\pi$ to show that the set
$$\{ n+2m \pi : n \in \mathbb {N}, m \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ok, I'm typing my try...

Comment: Could you look through the update, please?